# Cannot mount GFS2 filesystem on Raspberry Pi with DRBD

Tags: nas, raspberry-pi, storage, raspbian

I've been trying to setup a pair of Raspberry Pis with DRBD+GFS2, in a dual-primary configuration.

I've successfully got working:

- all packages installed
- DRBD userland packages built from source and working
- the 2 systems syncing an `r0` device on `/dev/drbd0`

At this point I am having issues with getting the `/dev/drbd0` device to mount on my `/data` dir. I get the error:

```
# mount -t gfs2 -o noatime,nodiratime,noquota /dev/drbd0 /data
mount: mount(2) failed: /data: No such file or directory
```

When I check my dmesg, I can see an error related to the `lock_dlm` protocol:

```
# dmesg | grep gfs
[159886.958163] gfs2: GFS2 installed
[159886.973908] gfs2: can't find protocol lock_dlm
[159925.272982] gfs2: can't find protocol lock_dlm
[160108.204231] gfs2: can't find protocol lock_dlm
[160139.555143] gfs2: can't find protocol lock_dlm
[161752.501161] gfs2: can't find protocol lock_dlm
```

The lock_dlm protocol is default when formatting GFS2:

```
mkfs.gfs2 -p lock_dlm -j 2 -t nfs:export /dev/drbd0
```

I've been doing some research on this, and as far as I can tell, the latest Rasbian kernel on the Raspberry Pi I'm using ***should support this*** and have the options enabled, notably `CONFIG_GFS2_FS_LOCKING_DLM`.

I'm having trouble verifying this, I'm not sure where to check.

I am not using custom compiled a kernel at this moment.

Can anyone advise how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: I’m not familiar with GFS2, but I found a module called `dlm` that’s not automatically loaded with `gfs2`. Maybe that’s required somehow?

Comment: I found that there is a package called `dlm-controld` but I cannot find on the Pis I've setup any package called `dlm`. It's also not listed on the debian package dependency list: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gfs2-utils
Any idea what this `dlm` package might mean? I'm trying to work this out, but I think it has something to do with kernel support.

Comment: I’m not referring to a package but a kernel module, present in `/lib/modules` on Raspbian. You can load it using `modprobe`.

Comment: I spent some time working on it, and got DLM running, but experienced the same issue. I managed to get everything working (Pacemaker, DLM, Corosync).
When I try to mount, I noticed that in the dmesg the error still `[ 3995.934192] gfs2: can't find protocol lock_dlm`.
Using `journalctl` I found another message `raspberrypi4.local.lan kernel: gfs2: can't find protocol lock_dlm`. Seems that it might still be a kernel issue that I need to track down and verify. If anyone knows anything about how to verify, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Turns out, its almost definitely something to do with `CONFIG_GFS2_FS_LOCKING_DLM`
I found a question at stackexchange that solved the same issue by recompiling the kernel: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439311/unable-to-mount-gfs2-file-system-on-debian-stretch-probable-dlm-mis-config

However, they failed to provide any details of how they did this smoothly. I have tried, and its been quite frustrating. If anyone knows how I can move forward with this, I'd really appreciate the help. :)